# Issue with rendering <ul> list elements with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a Angular View which render the `<li>` elements using `ng-repeat`

The `<li>` elements have the following CSS

```
li:last-child {

    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}

li:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

Basically, I am trying to create round corner for first and last li element. But the issue is that angular apply the style-sheet to each li element treating as first element (or last element if I cange the order of above style) while rendering each successive element. Any help please?

**update:**

Here is the HTML

```
<ul ng-repeat="artist in artists" >
                <li ><a href="http://www.google.com" >{{artist.firstName}}</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Controller is very simple and works fine with Json data. Lets say that artists is populated perfectly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the effect that occurs? Also can you paste your `ng-repeat` html, and possibly the controller code where the `$scope` is set.

Comment: You have probably put the `ng-repeat` directive on the `<ul>` instead of putting it on the `<li>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code means: for every artist in the `artists` array, generate the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com" >{{artist.firstName}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

That's not what you want. What you want is a single `ul`, and multiple `li` inside:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="artist in artists"><a href="http://www.google.com" >{{artist.firstName}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Just looking at the generated HTML in your browser dev tools window would have allowed you to find the problem.

Comment: Oops! That was a stupid mistake. Thanks very much to correct me.